# Removing certain sublists from a nested list based on a condition

Tags: python, list, nested

So, I have a nested list (Let's call it A). It has a length of 2, and they should be considered separate lists. I want to iterate through these 2 separately, and remove the sublists that don't have equal length. For example, I want my output to be the same as A but with [['Table heading']] removed because it is not the same length as the other nested lists.

```
A=[[[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']],
  [['x'],['y'],['z'],['w']],
  [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']],
  [['11'], ['22'], ['33'], ['44']]],
  [[['Table heading']],
  [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']],
  [['X'], ['Y'], ['Z'], ['W']],
  [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]]]

 output=[[[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']],
  [['x'],['y'],['z'],['w']],
  [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']],
  [['11'], ['22'], ['33'], ['44']]],
  [[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']],
  [['X'], ['Y'], ['Z'], ['W']],
  [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]]]
```

Comment: What rule governs what gets removed? For instance, why isn't Table Heading kept as the length of the rest aren't equal to its length... and what'd happen if *everything* was a different length?

Comment: O_O can you simplify this example

Comment: the reason table heading gets removed is because it is not the same length as the other ones, all other ones have a length of 4, and table heading has a length of 1

Comment: The reason I'm providing this example is because I'm extracting tables from word doc and this is the format they appear

Comment: @Mel sure... but why isn't it the other way around? One could argue that Table Heading should stay as it's a length of 1 and all the others aren't length 1 so should be removed... so there must be some criteria? Is it for instance, they all are length 4 or they can't be length 1... and what'd happen in `A[1]` if the last row was `[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5']]` ?

Comment: @JonClements I would want majority length to rule. So if that last row is added, then I would want it gone as well.

Comment: @Mel and if there's no majority?

Comment: From my experience, I know there will be majority but if there isn't, then output nothing.

Comment: @Mel okay... think my answer should work then... or not... let me re-think...

Comment: @Mel what about ties? If there's 2 rows with 2 columns, and 2 rows with 4 columns... what should happen?

Comment: @JonClements, I'm not sure. The two tables aren't supposed to have the same cols. My above example is of two different tables extracted from a word document. These two tables ( in this example) both have four columns and four rows. Albeit one of them could have three rows and three cols and the other one two rows and two columns. But sometimes, there is a table heading that get's extracted with the table. My goal is to identify it there is table heading or not, and delete it. So later on, I can convert this to pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Mel I wasn't referring to ties across tables... more if it was possible and what should happen if table 1 had two rows with two columns and two rows with four columns... If you're trying to put these into dataframe(s) then it's probably easier to dump it all into a DF (there's ways of forcing the above in) and then using the DF to drop the rubbish... Also.. the format you've ended up with is odd there... I've never had issues using the `docx` library to pull tables from documents and get them into a dataframe without this sort of processing... so maybe you're taking a long path than needed...

Comment: @JonClements, I don't think that would happen but if it were, I would extract both tables. I used docx2python to import the word document. I was looking to extract certain tables from these documents. And I have a file of these documents. Hence, I'm using a regex search method to find these tables and later convert them into dataframes. Do you have a better suggestion? thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @JonClements Or how can I convert A to two separate dataframes without table heading there? I would want to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```py
[ y for x in A for y in x if len(y) == 4]
```

Or in readable format.

```py
out = []
for inner in A:
     for inner_inner in inner:
          if len(inner_inner) == 4:
               out.append(inner_inner)
```

If you don't know the size of inner list but, you know that there is only one list that do not match in size, you can do like this.

```py
out = []
for inner in A:
     for inner_inner in inner:
         inner_size = len(inner_inner) 
         try:
             if inner_size == previous_size:
                 out.append(inner_inner)
          except NameError:
                  previous_size = inner_size
                  out.append(inner_inner)
```

This one have a default, if the first inner_inner element is to removed, the entire list elements will be removed instead of the first one.

Or like this

```py
from collections import Counter

size = Counter([ len(y) for x in A for y in x ]).most_common(1)[0][0]
[ y for x in A for y in x if len(y) == size]
```

This solution loop two time over the entire list, depending on list sizes this could be a limitation.

Comment: Thank you for this but this is hypothetical example, where I know the len of the inner, and I only want the sublists with len=4. But how would I set the len programiticlaly?

Comment: A=[[[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']],
  [['x'],['y'],['z'],['w']],
  [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']],
  [['11'], ['22'], ['33'], ['44']]],
[[['Table heading']],
[['A'], ['B'], ['C']],
[['X'], ['Y'], ['Z']],
[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]]]
How would I determine the length separately for each, for example, the most common length is 4 in the first table, and 3 in the second table. So I want the most common length in each table.

Comment: Based on your recommendations, this is how I would address if the lengths of the tables were different:                                                 A_new=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    Size=Counter([len(y) for y in A[i]]).most_common(1)[0][0]
    new=[num for num in A[i] if len(num)==Size]
    A_new.append(new)

Comment: @Mel update your post and add your comment in it, the format will be easier to read .

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It goes to delete the element unless they are not list anymore.

```
def  delete_odd(A):
    if isinstance(A[0],list)==False:
        return
    def delete_elem(a,if_not):
        print(a,'  ',if_not,'   ')

        i = 0
        while i<len(a):
            if len(a[i])!=if_not:
                del a[i]
            else:
                i+=1

    if len(A)<=2:
        pass
    else:
        n1 = len(A[0])
        n2 = len(A[1])
        n3 = len(A[2])
        if n1==n2:
            n = n1
        elif n2==n3:
            n = n2

        delete_elem(A,if_not=n)
    i = 0
    while i<len(A):
        delete_odd(A[i])
        i+=1




A = [[[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']],
  [['x'],['y'],['z'],['w']],
  [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']],
  [['11'], ['22'], ['33'], ['44']]],
  [[['Table heading']],
  [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']],
  [['X'], ['Y'], ['Z'], ['W']],
  [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]]]
delete_odd(A)

print(A)
#output
[[[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']], [['x'], ['y'], ['z'], ['w']], [['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']], [['11'], ['22'], ['33'], ['44']]], [[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']], [['X'], ['Y'], ['Z'], ['W']], [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]]]
```